# Comparing `language` items to vectors

Tags: r, comparison, formula

I collect a list of formulas with e.g.,

```
g <- list( c("allo",3) ~ 23, c("toto",4) ~ 29)
```

I then have the following variables `u = "toto"` and `v = 4`. I would like to check if any of the left-hand side of the equations matches `c(u, v)`. It is easy to extract the first left-hand side term, with e.g., `g[[1]][[2]]` but this term has class `language`,

```
str(g[[1]][[2]])
# language c("allo", 3)
```

How can I compare a `language` expression to a `chr` vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `eval` or even `call`

```
sapply(g, \(x)identical(eval(x[[2]]), c(u,v)))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

---

```
sapply(g, \(x)identical(x[[2]], call('c',u,v)))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

---

```
sapply(g, \(x)x[[2]] == call('c',u,v))
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Note that if you have `u` and `v` in a list form:

```
w <- list(u, v)
z <- as.call(c(quote(c), w))
sapply(g, \(x)x[[2]] == z)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: `call` indeed returns `language` elements! Very neat. The present solutions do not use `substitute`, contrary to the @r2evans proposal; using `eval` or `call` instead.

Comment: I selected this response at it offers more variation. In my plans, the top one was better, as c(u,v) was actually an argument of a function.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substitute` to look for equality.

```r
g <- list( c("allo",3) ~ 23, c("toto",4) ~ 29)
substitute(c(u, v), list(u = "toto", v = 4))
# c("toto", 4)
g[[2]][[2]]
# c("toto", 4)
sapply(g, function(.g) identical(.g[[2]], substitute(c(u, v), list(u = "toto", v = 4))))
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```